# How do I turn my pi3 back on?

Tags: pi-3, kodi, power-management

I'm using the LibraELEC image on a new Pi3.

When I navigate to the power icon (using mouse on the desktop, or the corresponding button on a remote control) it offers a menu for cancel, reboot, or shutdown.

I choose shutdown, and a few seconds later the monitor shows “no signal”.

Ok, now how do I turn it back on again?  Pressing the same remote button does nothing.  Moving the mouse or pressing keys on a keyboard does nothing.

What would be *useful* is a sleep mode like I get on my “regular” HTPC.  Any user input device will wake it up, and it instantly remembers where I was.  And if I do perform a full shutdown, there's a button on the ATX case to start it again.

I want a useful sleep/standby mode on the Pi3/kodi, with an automatic no-activity timeout.  And if I *must* reboot rather than sleep, it certainly needs a way to turn it on!

Comment: Instead of changing the question you should have asked a new question. Changes to the question like this one with existing answers creates a mismatch between question and answer.

Comment: As Steve pointed out the last change is changing the question to that extend that it invalidates the existing answers to a certain point. It would be preferable to stick with the answered question here and take the updated question (based on what you've learned as you said) simply to a new question. This will be answered too (hopefully) and all participants win and achieve StackExchange goals.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to restart the Pi are:-

1. Cycle power, or
2. Connect a switch to the reset pins on the Pi

If neither of these suits you DO NOT TURN OFF; the Pi uses less power than most devices (TV, Computers) on standby.

Comment: Uses less power: that would explain why it’s not a priority. But I do want it to stop streaming over the network, etc.

Comment: That is a different question.

Answer (score 2):

The Pi does not have a low power/sleep mode because it uses so little energy as it is. One often quoted figure is that it costs less than $1 a month to run 24/7.

To restart simply disconnect and recoonect the power. To avoid damaging the micro USB connnector on the Pi you should do this at the wall rather than the Pi.

There are several third party products which place a switch inline with the power cord like this [one](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1620), you would need a USB to micro USB adapter or cable to use this one.

[image]

Another option is to pug the Pi's powersupply into a [power bar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DM0BP2G) and use that to switch the power on and off. Some of these even have high speed USB charging points built in allowing you to use just a USB cable to connect your Pi to power.

[image]

Yet, another option is to use a remote control [socket](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087EIDRS) to toggle the power and restart your Pi.

[image]

If you are the DIY type you could followe this [instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-Raspberry-Pi-ON-w-Remote-Control/).

Some users have also used the USB port on their TV to power the PI. I don't recommend this method for a couple of reasons. First USB ports are not designed to provide enough current to properly power the Pi. Second this method does not perfrom a proper shutdown of the Pi and can result in corruption of the SD card.

Comment: That is completely impractical.  The project is hidden behind the wall-mounted TV and the wall plug cannot be reached.  One can turn on the monitor from in bed, so it would be objectionable in this age to have to go flip a switch at the device.

Comment: @JDługosz The first few solutions I mention may be impractical, but only based on facts that you failed to mention in your queestion.

Comment: *Failed to mention:* I didn’t think it was a “problem”, rather a configuration issue perhaps with the newer hardware version. It never occured to me that it wouldn’t work like every other box I’ve ever seen.

Comment: As for something like you’ve pictured, I'm already set up using X-10.  But that adds to the expense and requires a *different* remote control to operate.  I'm not grappling for a remote way to cycle power; just flabbergasted that it would be needed.

Comment: @JDługosz You should keep in mind that the Pi was not designed to be a media player, nor was it designed to be a mass marketed consumer product. It was designed to teach computing, so it should come as no surprise that it is missing features when compared to a dedicated media player.